# Make a node that doesn't move after collision iOS 8

Tags: swift, ios8, sprite-kit

I have nodes (sand) falling downwards.

I have other nodes (walls) that are static.

How do I make the walls not move when the sand collides with it?

```
    let wall = SKSpriteNode(texture: chosen)

    wall.position = location

    wall.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: sprite.frame.width)
    wall.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    wall.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = BLOCK

    self.addChild(wall)
```

//////////

```
    let sand = SKSpriteNode (imageNamed: img)
    var randLoc = arc4random_uniform(26)
    sand.position = CGPointMake(location.x - CGFloat(10) + CGFloat(randLoc), location.y)
    self.addChild(sand)

    //gravity
    sand.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: sand.frame.width)
    sand.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true

    //contact
    sand.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = self.PARTICLE
    sand.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = self.BLOCK | self.PARTICLE
```

Comment: if you have wall.physicsBody?.dynamic = false & sand.physicsBody?.dynamic = true then you should be able to detect the contact without the walls being pushed/moved by the sand.

Comment: Yes thank you! That worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you have `wall.physicsBody?.dynamic = false` & `sand.physicsBody?.dynamic = true` then you should be able to detect the contact without the walls being pushed/moved by the sand. - Daniel Mihaila

https://stackoverflow.com/users/4963031/daniel-mihaila